# Put a Custom Date next to string in MS VBA

Tags: vba

I am creating a VBA Macro that will fire emails to my distribution list every Wednesday.

I was wondering if there was a way to add a dynamic custom date that updates every week when I open the distribution list?

The part I want to add my custom date is here: emailItem.Subject = "Training Report - DD-MM-YYYY"

I want the date to be the **last Sunday of every week.**

Many thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Email_With_Attachment()

Dim emailApplication As Object
Dim emailItem As Object


Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)

'Now build the email.

emailItem.To = Range("A2").Value

emailItem.CC = Range("B2").Value

emailItem.Subject = "Training Report - DD-MM-YYYY"
```

Comment: last sunday of every week or month?

Comment: "last Sunday of every week" or the last Sunday of the last/current week?

Comment: Last Sunday should be `Date + (1 - Weekday(Date))` and next Sunday `Date + (8 - Weekday(Date))`... Format it as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
i might have misunderstood you. If you need the last sunday instead of the next sunday you just need to replace the nextSunday part of the code with this:

```
Dim lastSunday as Date
lastSunday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(Now), Now)
```

Function [Weekday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) returns an integer representing day of the week for supplied date parameter. The values it returns are as follows:

1. for sunday or (vbSunday)
2. for monday or (vbMonday)
3. for tuesday of (vbTuesday)

and so on. So for today (23.11.2021) which is tuesday function will return number 3.

Function [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) adds in our case because of the first parameter "d" number of days to provided date.

The last function we used is [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) which returns a string representation based on provided date and format "dd-MM-yyyy"

So the part of your code where you set the subject should look something like this:

```
...
Dim nextSunday as Date
nextSunday = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Now) + 8, Now)

emailItem.Subject = "Training Report - " & Format(nextSunday, "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot for your help! :)

This is the code I needed:
Dim lastSunday as Date
lastSunday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(Now), Now)